# I do not recognize the command "ionic"

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm running applications in ionic, everything was fine until I do not know what command I ran that now I do not recognize the "ionic" command.
It has something to worry about.
And install the command:

```
npm install -g ionic
```

> Ionic: The term 'ionic' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file or executable program. Check if you typed the
>   name correctly, or if you included a path, check That the path is
>   correct and try again. Online: 1 Character: 1 + Ionic CLI + ~~~~~ +
>   CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (ionic: String) [],
>   CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId:
>   CommandNotFoundException

[image]

[image]

Comment: run this npm install -g ionic@latest to get latest version of ionic

Comment: @AnilMaurya Many thanks for the quick comment but I still do not recognize the command :c

Answer (score 1):

It seems look like ionic is not properly installed.You should install using below command globally . So you can access ionic command any where in cmd line not in particular folder.

**npm install -g ionic**

If you are unable to run this command make sure you have installed latest  [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) or npm.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is **too long**.So just use a simple path like below.

```
c:\myporject\ionicproj>
```

**Note:** You must move into the root folder of the Ionic project too before typing any `Ionic CLI` commands.

[**See this too**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331276/ionic-framework-ionic-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command).

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt reply I followed your comment but I still do not recognize the command :c

Comment: Did you move into your Ionic root folder? Can you show the latest error image?

Comment: Ionic: The term 'ionic' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or executable program. Check if you typed the name correctly, or if you included a path, check
That the path is correct and try again.
Online: 1 Character: 1
+ Ionic CLI
+ ~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (ionic: String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331276/ionic-framework-ionic-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: Another one:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454810/ionic-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command