# Ionic Application - Ionic serve issues

Tags: html, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am creating a simple ionic application and successfully installed the following below commands in windows.

1) $ npm install -g ionic cordova
2) $ ionic start helloWorld blank --type=ionic-angular
3) $ cd helloWorld
4) $ ionic serve
Source :- https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/intro/installation/

Still I am getting the below screenshot error in CLI.

Please let me know if  anything I am missing.

[image]

Comment: you need to add ionic to the path, or reference it from where it is installed. It is not installed in the directory you are trying to run it from

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59800889/8296499

Answer (score 0):

This is the command to install Ionic.

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli
```

you should install ionic@cli not just Ionic.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install ionic cli using this command:
**npm install -g @ionic/cli**